# C# encrypt string

Tags: c#, encryption

I got the following code to encrypt a string.

```
    private void Crypt(int n, int m, int d)
    {
        n = Convert.ToInt32(n);
        m = Convert.ToInt32(m);
        d = Convert.ToInt32(d);


        // make a block from the string
        string invoerstring = invoer.Text;
        int stringlength = invoerstring.Length; 
        var blok = invoer.Text.PadRight(stringlength, ' ').Substring(0, stringlength);

        // the letters are shifted d times
        char [] buf = invoerstring.ToArray<char>();
        foreach (char c in buf)
        {
           var letter = uitvoer.Text += (char)( c + (char)d);
        }

        // shift characters inside a block
        var shift = String.Concat(invoerstring.Skip(m).Concat(invoerstring.Take(m)));
        uitvoer.Text = shift;  


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Crypt(8,2,1);

    }

    private void clearbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        invoer.Text = "";
        uitvoer.Text = "";
    }


}
```

}

This is the explanation of the exercise:

- crypt n m d text
- text is padded with spaces until its length is a multiple of n
- the characters in text are circulary shifted in the alphabet by the displacement d
- example: if d = 1 then 'a' -> 'b' ,  'b' -> 'c' .... etc... 'z' -> 'a'
- text is divided in blocks of length n characters
- inside every block of n  the characters are circulary shifted m times to the left
- the shifted groups are concatenated

When I run my code the letters aren't shifted d times. For example the string:
"aap noot mies" has to change to "q oppubbjft    n" (When Crypt is Crypt(8,2,1)). What do I need to change to get this result?

Comment: btw, why you're trying to build a encryption function when you have native support for this in .NET? Homework?

Comment: My guess is that adding characters `c + (char)d` and then casting the result to a `char` isn't doing what you think.  Try evaluating the pieces in the debugger.

Comment: Why on Earth do you have `n = Convert.ToInt32(n);` and so on, where `n` has compile-time type `int` already?

Comment: In your `foreach` loop you create a local variable `letter` that you do not use? The `uitvoer.Text` property is appended to in that loop, but then later, after the loop, you overwrite `uitvoer.Text`, and it looks like you lose the "effect" of the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Need to this in C#, it's homework. When I evaluate every seperate piece, it does what I want to do it. How can I prevent that I overwrite uitvoer.Text?

Comment: The way you create `blok` doesn't really work. You pad with spaces until the string has the length it already had from the beginning. So that adds no spaces. Then the `Substring` will not change anything either. Also you never use `blok` later in your code, so why try to calculate it?

Answer (score 3):

You have many problems/oddities:

- You're `Convert`ing a bunch of `int`s to `Int32`s, but the former is just syntatic sugar for the latter.
- Your `PadRight` call is going to return the initial string since the length you pass is equal to the length of the `string`.
- Your `Substring` call is going to return the initial string.
- You never use `blok`.
- You never actually split the input into blocks or pad it.
- `string` already implements `IEnumerable` (a fact you're already implicitly using), so there's no need to convert it to an array just to loop over it.
- You never use `letter`.
- `(char)( c + (char)d)` does not implement the [Caeser cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) you're looking for, you'll end up converting some letters into non-letters (except in one degenerate case).
- You're concatenating the result of the shift into `uitvoer.Text` (without clearing it) and then overwriting it later without using it.
- You're calling the single parameter static version of `Concat` (which converts the object it's passed into a `string`) and passing it a `string`.

Start by fixing the ones you know how to do and edit the question if you get stuck.